# Gradle copy and filter task not executed

Tags: gradle

We are filtering an xml file replacing some tokens with gradle properties.

But the filtering (i.e. copy task) is not executed when we just change the properties in our build.gradle file.

How should we modify our script so that the filtering is performed each time or at least when the template and/or the build.gradle has been modified.

This we have:

```
war.doFirst {
   delete 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'

   copy {
        from 'build.gradle'
        from 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/'
        into 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/'
        include '*-template.*'

        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('-template', '')
        }

        expand(gaeApp: "$gaeApp", gaeAppVersion: "$gaeAppVersion")
    }
}
```

I just ran some test where the filtering worked. I am confused... I am sure that it sometimes does not!

So after good input from Vampire we tried this

```
war {
    inputs.file "build.gradle"

    exclude 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'

    // filesMatching('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**/*-template.*') {
    filesMatching('**/*-template.*') {

        println "WAR template: $it"

       rename { it.replace '-template', '' }
       expand gaeApp: gaeApp, gaeAppVersion: gaeAppVersion
    }
}
```

A dollar and a dime to anyone who can explain why the `filesMatching('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**/*-template.*')`does not work!

BUT the biggest problem is that even if the filesMatching locates the template file the `appengine-web.xml` that is placed inside the WAR is not a processed version of `appengine-web-template.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those properties to the inputs of the task like

```
war.inputs.property 'gaeApp', gaeApp
war.inputs.property 'gaeAppVersion', gaeAppVersion
```

so that gradle knows the input changed, otherwise it cannot know when the input is different.

But besides that, you should not (need not) use a `copy { }` block in there.
The `war` task itself is an implicit copy spec, so you should be able just doing something like

```
war {
    inputs.property 'gaeApp', gaeApp
    inputs.property 'gaeAppVersion', gaeAppVersion

    exclude 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'

    filesMatching('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**/*-template.*') {
        rename { it.replace '-template', '' }
        expand gaeApp: gaeApp, gaeAppVersion: gaeAppVersion
    }
}
```

Comment: Just ran into problem with this solution. It does not copy/filter when we make changes to build.gradle

Comment: Depends on what you change. For the task to be run, the inputs and / or outputs have to change. So if you want to always run the task after the gradle file changed, add the gradle file to the inputs with `inputs.file ...`. If you just want to make sure it is run the next time someone executes it after your change because you changed e. g. the matching pattern, either add the matching pattern to the inputs like the variables or version the task like `inputs.property 'version', 1` which you manually increase after you changed the task setup without affecting inputs / outputs.

Comment: Sorry for my bad netiquette. I will make some new tests and upvote after that!

Comment: Whatever pattern suits you and matches your files is fine. I'd wonder though if what you quoted is really the right pattern, but as I said, as long as it matches the files you want, it is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have rechecked your answer. We still have some  strange issues with the filesMatching. I edited my initial question with that.

Comment: And even if the filesMatching now works the filtering does not!  Now I am really confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "the filtering does not"?

Comment: Btw. you don't have your properties as input anymore. So the task will not reexecute if the properties change without `build.gradle` changing.

Comment: And what does your `println` output?

Comment: And besides the other questions, what is the content of your `appengine-web-template.xml` file?

Comment: Hi Vampire and sorry for my absence. I don't remember exactly what went wrong but the solution below solved our problem. I don't have more time to investigate this problem at the moment. (I got no answer on the chat but I am new to the chat here and I may have chatted you in wrong way ...)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112756/discussion-between-gunnar-eketrapp-and-vampire

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for us in the end.

We moved the template to 'src/template/webapp' and removed the "-template" suffix,

```
war {
    inputs.file "build.gradle"
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/template/webapp' 
        expand gaeApp: gaeApp, gaeAppVersion: gaeAppVersion
    } 
}
```

Our problem with Vampire's solution must be related to the fact that the template file was in same directory as the file it was to replace.